# String manipulation in Python

Tags: python, regex, performance, time-complexity

Recently I gave a test on HackerRank and my question is:

Give a string return the most concise string that can be formed from it for example:

```
string = 'watson  Represents|watson represents|Watson represents a first step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.|first step into  Cognitive|Cognitive Systems; a new era|what does watson represent'
```

- The following string contains many duplicates like `Watson represents` we have to ignore extra spacing between characters or lower/upper case.`watson  Represents` `watson represents` are same thing.
- Semicolon and comma represent the same thing. For example `Cognitive Systems; a new era` is present inside `Watson represents a first step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.`
- Your final string should not contain any duplicates ignore lowercase/uppercase or extra space if you have

My Answer :

```
watson = 'watson  Represents|watson represents|Watson represents a first step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.|first step into  Cognitive|Cognitive Systems; a new era|what does watson represent'

import re

watson = re.sub(r';', r',', watson)  #replace the semicolon with colon
watson = watson.strip().split('|')
removeWatson = list(watson)

for i in range(len(watson)):

    for j in range(len(watson)):

        if j == i:
            continue

        if " ".join(watson[i].strip().lower().split()) in " ".join(watson[j].strip().lower().split()):
            removeWatson[i] = ''

print "|".join(filter(None, removeWatson))
```

My answer is definitely inefficient and I am wondering if you can suggest me to alternative way to solve this problem.

Most concise string is : `Watson represents a first step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.|what does watson represent`

Comment: Whats wrong with the result you got? Do you not want it to have the `|what does watson represent`?

Comment: Can you post a link to the HackerRank challenge?

Comment: It was a HackerRank test so difficult to find the link

Comment: @RobertR Answer is correct but highly inefficient code

Comment: @sorbet Could you post any doubt or issue with the question?

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla I was having trouble understanding what your actual question was. If inefficiency is your problem, perhaps this question is better suited to [StackExchange: Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'watson  Represents|watson represents|Watson represents a first   step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.|first step into  Cognitive|Cognitive Systems; a new era|what does watson represent'
ll=string.split("|")
ll.sort(key=len)
import re
ll2=[re.sub(r"\s+"," ",re.sub(r"[;,]+","",i.lower())) for i in ll]
j=1
k=0
for i in ll2:
    if re.findall(r"\b"+i.lower()+r"\b","|".join(ll2[j:]),flags=re.I):
        string=string.replace(ll[k],"",1)
    k=k+1
    j=j+1
print re.sub(r"^\|+|\|(?=\|)|\|+$","",string
```

You can do it in 1 loop using `re`.

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is that I am being asked to represent the original string exactly, i.e. I can reproduce the original from my most concise version.

In other words - compress it.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from zlib import compress, decompress

string = 'watson  Represents|watson represents|Watson represents a first step into cognitive systems, a new era of computing.|first step into  Cognitive|Cognitive Systems; a new era|what does watson represent'

print("Original length:", len(string))
compressed = compress(string)
print("Compressed length:", len(compressed))
decompressed = decompress(compressed)
print("Decompressed is equal:", decompressed == string)
```

Result is:

```
Original length: 198
Compressed length: 116
Decompressed is equal: True
```

Comment: We have to output the compressed string not length.

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla: you're missing the point: the interesting part is that zlib `compress` is able to squish it.  Obviously changing the program to print out the compressed binary representation is trivial.

Comment: When i printed out the binary representation that was something totally different, not even unicode characters. Any idea how will decode that?